# Interpolate with spline and keep exact knotted values

Tags: r, interpolation, spline

**Problem**

I'm playing around with splines and trying to connect mid months to interpolate the entire year starting with January 15th; however, I want to make sure that the mid point months are set correctly in the entire year.  That is, in each month I want the mid point (15th) to be the same from the original monthly data.  Currently, the code I have is not doing this and some of the values are quite different from the original code.  I'd like to make sure, if possible, those exact values fit in the data at the mid point (15th) of each month.

Is there a way to make sure those points from the original data are set correctly in the interpolated data so they are at the exact position of the midpoint (15th) of each month?

**Example:**

```
# Monthly data
df <- data.frame(x <- seq(1,12), 
                 y <- c(45, 54, 50 ,63, 70, 75, 80, 88, 76, 81, 63, 54))

# Interpolate with spline to daily data starting with 15th of January (351 days)
values <- spline(df$x, df$y, n = 351)$y

# Check values
# Original values
df$y

# New values at 15th of each month
values[c(1,31, 60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335)]
```

Output (Some round fine, but most are off):

```
> df$y
 [1] 45 54 50 63 70 75 80 88 76 81 63 54

> values[c(1,31, 60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335)]
 [1] 45.00000 54.21321 49.65891 60.61385 68.91151 73.89644 77.62606 87.33305 79.66860 79.27115 73.10543 54.71480
```

Desired Output:

```
    > df$y
     [1] 45 54 50 63 70 75 80 88 76 81 63 54

    > values[c(1,31, 60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335)]
     [1] 45 54 50 63 70 75 80 88 76 81 63 54
```

**Image:**

Red: Original month points

Black line: Points from spline interpolation
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to align things with calendar days, you might let R do the work of keeping track of the dates. This approach would also take care of leap years. At the end, you can then index by day starting with Jan. 15. Using this year as an example, code could look like:

```
  df <- data.frame(x=seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-15"), by="month", length.out=12), 
                   y = c(45, 54, 50 ,63, 70, 75, 80, 88, 76, 81, 63, 54))
   values_by_date <- splinefun(df$x, df$y)
#
# To get a value at every day between Jan 15 and Dec 15
#
 values <- values_by_date(seq.Date(df$x[1], tail(df$x,1), by="day"))
#
#  Check dates at mid month
#  Note that second index should be 32, not 31
#
 values[c(1,32, 60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335)]

[1] 45 54 50 63 70 75 80 88 76 81 63 54
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you might note that `df` can contain any set of dates (stored as R `Date` objects) and values for those days to be used as the basis for interpolation including for multiple years.  You can then either generate a vector of values for all days in the interval as shown in the code or you can use the `values_by_date` function directly to obtain values for any set of dates.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood how you presenting the answer.  This works perfect!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's more complicated than the answer provided by WaltS, but it works:

```
# Input data:
df <- data.frame(x <- seq(1,12),
                 y <- c(45, 54, 50 ,63, 70, 75, 80, 88, 76, 81, 63, 54))
# I use this dataframe to get the right position for the ticks
# The "offset_days" column is left 'empty' at start:
days_of_month <- data.frame(months=c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'),
                            days = c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31),
                            offset_days = 0)
# Offset: The day of month you want your ticks to be placed (should be between 1 and 28):
offset <- 15

# Fill the "offset_days" column with the appropriate day
for(i in 1:nrow(days_of_month)) {
  if(i == 1)
    days_of_month$offset_days[i] <- offset
  else
    days_of_month$offset_days[i] <- days_of_month$offset_days[i-1] + days_of_month$days[i-1]
}

# Calculate the spline with the offset days as x value:
sp <- spline(days_of_month$offset_days, df$y, 351)

plot(sp$x, sp$y, type='l', xlim=c(0,365), xaxt='n')
lines(days_of_month$offset_days, df$y, type='o', col='red')
axis(side=1, at=cumsum(days_of_month$days), lab=rep('',12))
axis(side=1, at=days_of_month$offset_days, lab=days_of_month$months, tck=0)
```

The output:

[image: Output]

The red line shows your original data, and the black line is the smoothed data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How is this different than @WaltS?  Why do you think this approach is better?

Comment: @Amstell It's a bit more complicated, as it requires you to manually feed the length of each month... It avoids dealing with date values (which often confuse me), and let's you define the offset (you could place the data along any day in the month by changing the `offset` variable)

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll hang on to this if I have to use a spline outside of using dates.  Awesome answer!

Comment: @Amstell The whole point of using a spline is to interpolate the data between your observations, so the point is which approach you'll use to fix the points of your input data. Both answers give you that. But if you don't use the interpolated data, why do you want a spline?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as far as the difference.  I need to make sure the mid points are the monthly data, and then interpolate between.  I feel WaltS provided this answer; whereby, your method is doing what I did in my question above.  I would like to maintain accuracy of the data and make sure the midpoints are exact.  Can you maybe explain how the answers are different and why yours is interpolating the data as opposed to WaltS where you feel is not?

Comment: @Amstell WaltS' answer provides you with a way to get the X coordinates of every pont... so do I (the ways differ, but the result is the same). I'm not doing what you did: I improved it, by ensuring that the X coordinate matched the 15th of every month (as you can see in the plot I posted, which acomplishes your goal)

Comment: Thanks for your help and clarification.  I thought the results looked the same, but thought maybe I was missing something.  I'll certainly hang on to your code and I appreciate your time.